# HtmlUnit: Prefilled Input elements suddenly empty when submitting

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I am new to htmlunit and I am using it for the first time.

Currently I try to automatically fill and submit details as part of some automated test suite.
I first enter some credid card details into input elements and then I click a submit button which triggers some javascript.

The problem I have is that when I click the submit input seems that the input text I added and the selections I made are lost.
I verified this by running a local web server with the same html and added debug output to the javascript which is executed.
The debug output shows me that all of the input elements are empty or have their initial values.

Here is the code I use (its scala code but as u can see its similar to java):
In the `println` before the `submitButton.click()` I can see that the values are set. 
The `collectedAlerts` list collects all `alert` calls, which I use to get debug output, from the javascript. And this shows me that the input elements are empty.

```
object WebsiteAutofill {
  val webClient = new WebClient()
  webClient.getOptions.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
  webClient.getOptions.setRedirectEnabled(true)
  webClient.getOptions.setCssEnabled(true)

  val collectedAlerts = new util.ArrayList[String]
  webClient.setAlertHandler(new CollectingAlertHandler(collectedAlerts))

  val url = "http://localhost:8000/secupay.html"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val iframe: HtmlPage = webClient.getPage(url)

    val cardName: HtmlTextInput = iframe.getElementById("card_name").asInstanceOf[HtmlTextInput]
    val cardNumber: HtmlTextInput = iframe.getElementById("card_number").asInstanceOf[HtmlTextInput]

    val cardExpiryMonth: HtmlSelect = iframe.getElementById("card_expiry_month").asInstanceOf[HtmlSelect]
    val cardExpiryYear: HtmlSelect = iframe.getElementById("card_expiry_year").asInstanceOf[HtmlSelect]
    val cardCvv: HtmlTextInput = iframe.getElementById("card_cvc").asInstanceOf[HtmlTextInput]

    val submitButton: HtmlSubmitInput = iframe.getElementById("btn_submit").asInstanceOf[HtmlSubmitInput]

    cardName.setValueAttribute("Card Owner")
    cardName.setText("Card Owner")

    cardNumber.setValueAttribute("4024007186180153")
    cardNumber.setText("4024007186180153")

    cardExpiryMonth.setSelectedAttribute(
      cardExpiryMonth.getOptionByValue("1"),
      true
    ): Page
    cardExpiryMonth.setAttribute("value", "1")

    cardExpiryYear.setSelectedAttribute(
      cardExpiryYear.getOptionByValue("2021"),
      true
    ): Page
    cardExpiryYear.setAttribute("value", "2021")

    cardCvv.setValueAttribute("123")
    cardCvv.setText("123")

    println(s"""
         |card name value: ${cardName
                 .getAttribute("value")} | ${cardName.getText}
         |numbervalue: ${cardNumber.getAttribute("value")}
         |expire month: ${cardExpiryMonth.getAttribute("value")}
         |expire year: ${cardExpiryYear.getAttribute("value")}
         |cvv: ${cardCvv.getAttribute("value")}
         |""".stripMargin)

    val redirectPage: HtmlPage = submitButton.click().asInstanceOf[HtmlPage]
    println(s"Redirect url: ${redirectPage.getUrl.toString}")

    val htmlBody = redirectPage.getWebResponse.getContentAsString
    Files.write(Paths.get("out.html"), htmlBody.getBytes("utf-8"))

    println(s"CollectedAlerts: ${collectedAlerts.size()}")
    collectedAlerts.forEach(println(_))
  }
}
```

You can find the `secupay.html` here: https://pastebin.com/xqGJm3TV
And the `my_payment_creditcard.js` javascript here: https://pastebin.com/r1by0t2r

At line 188 of the javascript I added some debug `alert` calls and those show me that all of the input elements are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem.
There was a validation function which is only called on `keyup` events and those are not fired when using `setText` or `setValueAttribute`.
I used the `type` method instead and now it works.